# C binary tree search

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree

I'm trying to find node in binary tree, but the function returns nothing, NULL!
By the way, in printf, in

```
if ((cond = strcmp(head->word, word_to_search)) == 0)
```

the result is right, it just does not return value, probably I'm making it wrong with recursion, I don't know. By the way if I wrap last return NULL in else, it does return valid pointer, but it causes a warning...

```
struct count_tree *
binaryt_search(struct count_tree *head, char *word_to_search)
{
    int cond = 0;
    if (head != NULL) {
        if ((cond = strcmp(head->word, word_to_search)) == 0) {
            printf("Found %s %d\n", head->word, head->count);
            return head;
        }
        else if (cond < 0) {
            binaryt_search(head->left, word_to_search);
        }
        else {
            binaryt_search(head->right, word_to_search);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: You should add "return" statement before calling binaryt_search

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve].

Comment: It works! Thank you, @axel7083! but why does it work this way?

Comment: At the moment, you just call the functions and throw away the result. Execution reaches the `return NULL` so the calling function will see `NULL`. By returning the result of the recursive calls, you pass the result up the recursion chain.

Comment: Your recursion works like the top-level call, just on the subtrees. So say in `main` you call `binaryt_search` and ask "Does the tree contain x?". If the head node isn't null or doesn't have x, it asks the respective sub-tree: "Do you contain x?" and so on, until an aswer is found. The sub-trees then "report back" to the parent node and the head node reports back to `main`.

Comment: Oh I see, now I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `return` the results of the calls to `binaryt_search()`.
So,

```
binaryt_search(head->left, word_to_search);
```

becomes

```
return binaryt_search(head->left, word_to_search);
```

and

```
binaryt_search(head->right, word_to_search);
```

becomes

```
return binaryt_search(head->right, word_to_search);
```